# Verifying CRC32 of UDP given .jpg file of payload

Tags: python, udp, checksum, packet, crc32

I'm running a server that receives UDP packets that contain a 2 byte CRC32 polynomial and a variable number of XOR'd DWORDs corresponding to a .jpg file. The packets also contain the index of the corresponding DWORD in the .jpg file for each DWORD in the packet. I am also given the actual .jpg file.

For example, the packet could contain 10 DWORDs and specify the starting index as 3, so we can expect the received DWORDs to correspond with the 4th through 11th DWORDs making up the .jpg.

I want to verify the integrity of each of the DWORDs by comparing their CRC32 values against  the CRC32 values of the corresponding DWORDs in the .jpg.

I thought that the proper way to do this would be to divide each DWORD in the packet and its corresponding DWORD in the .jpg by the provided CRC polynomial and analyze the remainder. If the remainders are the same after doing these divisions, then there is no problem with the packet. However, even with packets that are guaranteed to be correct, these remainders are never equal.

Here is how I'm reading the bytes of the actual .jpg and splitting them up into DWORDs:

```
def split(data):
    # Split the .jpg data into DWORDs
    chunks = []
    for i in range(0, len(data), 4):
        chunks.append(data[i: i + 4])
    return chunks

def get_image_bytes():
    with open("dog.jpg", "rb") as image:
        f = image.read()
        jpg_bytes = split(f)
        return jpg_bytes
```

Now I have verified my split() function works and to my knowledge, get_image_bytes() reads the .jpg correctly by calling image.read().

After receiving a packet, I convert each DWORD to binary and perform  the mod 2 division like so:

```
jpg_bytes = get_image_bytes()
crc_key_bin = '1000110111100' # binary representation of the received CRC32 polynomial
d_words = [b'\xc3\xd4)v', ... , b'a4\x96\xbb']

iteration = 0 # For simplicity, assume the packet specified that the starting index is 0
for d in d_words:
    d_bin = format(int(d.hex(), 16), "b") # binary representation of the DWORD from the packet
    jpg_dword = format(int(jpg_bytes[iteration].hex(), 16), "b") # binary representation of the corresponding DWORD in dog.jpg
    remainder1 = mod2div(d_bin, crc_key_bin)      # <--- These remainders should be
    remainder2 = mod2div(jpg_dword, crc_key_bin)  # <--- equal, but they're not!

    iteration += 1
```

I have tested the mod2div() function, and it returns the expected remainder after performing mod 2 division.

Where am I going wrong? I'm expecting the 2 remainders to be equal, but they never are. I'm not sure if the way I'm reading the bytes from the .jpg file is incorrect, if I'm performing the mod 2 division with the wrong values, or if I'm completely misunderstanding how to verify the CRC32 values. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's no such thing as a "2 byte CRC32 polynomial". A 32-bit CRC needs 32-bits to specify the polynomial.

Second, a CRC polynomial is something that is fixed for a given protocol. Why is a CRC polynomial being transmitted, as opposed to simply specified? Are you sure it's the polynomial? Where is this all documented?

What does "XOR'd DWORDs" means? Exclusive-or'd with what?

And, yes, I think you are completely misunderstanding how to verify CRC values. All you need to do is calculate the check values on the message the same way it was done at the other end, and compare that to the check values that were transmitted. (That is true for any check value, not just CRCs.) However I cannot tell from your description what was calculated on what, or how.

Comment: Ah, I see where some of my confusion is. The "2 byte CRC32 polynomial" I'm referring to is actually called the "Repeating XOR Key" in the specs of my project. I'm not sure exactly what that is at all. I showed you the documentation for my project on another post. Although I still have some confusion, I have cleared some of it up since then. The DWORDs in the packet are referred to as "Repeating key XOR'd Cyclic Checksum CRC32 DWORDs", so I assumed they were XOR'd with the "Repeating XOR Key". However, I do notice there is a specific polynomial for CRC32 specified on the CRC wikipedia page...

Comment: I thought it would be as simple as running binascii.crc32() on the DWORDs in the packet and their corresponding DWORDs in the jpg bytes, but they don't match up like that etiher.

Comment: There are _many_ polynomials for [32-bit CRCs](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat-bits.32), as well as a panoply of possible initial values, final xor values, and bit reflections.